# How do I open multiple files with a program?

Tags: python, file

For example, opening many text files with notepad++ via python script. I need to open every file in a directory.

Comment: Iterate over each file in your directory, opening each file via `with open() as file:` construct.

Comment: @leaf no I think he wants to open in GUI mode. In linux you can do `gedit *` inside folder. dunno about windows.

Comment: Are you using windows or linux?

Comment: You can use `subprocess.popen()` in a loop to execute a shell command on each file.

Comment: windows 7, 64 bit.

Comment: Try this: `Start notepad++ *.txt` in powershell after entering the folder.

Comment: @Community♦ this is not a duplicate. It is very closely related, but not a duplicate.

Comment: @leaf It's a bot :P. Can it process comments?

Comment: Notepad++ provides Python module. Check this http://npppythonscript.sourceforge.net/docs/latest/notepad.html

Comment: @MYGz I know :-) I _was_ going to ask somebody to reopen the question, but its fine.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the *glob* and *fileinput* together

```
import fileinput
from glob import glob

file = glob('Sample*.txt')
for line in fileinput.input(file):
    pass
```

If you want to iterate multiple files then use :

```
for x in fileinput.input(['patterns.in', 'sample*.txt']):
    print x
```